# How to dynamically populate text based on data extension cell value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dynamic

How do I create dynamically populated text displaying within another block of dynamically populated text?

The e-mail has a line of script similar to this:

```
%%[VAR @block_a

IF ColumnA == "ValueA" OR ColumnA == "ValueB" THEN
  /* Panel 1 Message */
  SET @block_a = "Some text goes here %%DCValue1%%, %%DCValue2%%, %%DCValue3%%, rest of text"
 ELSE
  /* Panel 2 Message */
  SET @block_a = "Some text goes here %%DCValue1%%, %%DCValue2%% or %%DCValue3%%. rest of text"

ENDIF

]%%
```

It ends up displaying as:

> Some text goes here `%%DCValue1%%, %%DCValue2%%, %%DCValue3%%`, rest
>   of text

Maybe I'm missing something, but how do I get the values associated with the DCValue1, DCValue2, and DCValue3 to display instead of the AMPScript? The column headings in the Data Extension match what's in the AMPScript so I'm not sure what else to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are probably your best two options:

**Solution 1: TreatAsContent()**
*AMPScript TreatAsContent will treat the string or variable inside it as if it is coming from a Content Block and render all AMPscript or presonalization that is in the string.*

AMPSCRIPT BLOCK:

```
%%[VAR @block_a

IF ColumnA == "ValueA" OR ColumnA == "ValueB" THEN
  /* Panel 1 Message */
  SET @block_a = "Some text goes here %%DCValue1%%, %%DCValue2%%, %%DCValue3%%, rest of text"
 ELSE
  /* Panel 2 Message */
  SET @block_a = "Some text goes here %%DCValue1%%, %%DCValue2%% or %%DCValue3%%. rest of text"

ENDIF

]%%
```

OUTPUT Block in HTML:

```
%%=TreatAsContent(@block_a)=%%
```

**Solution 2: Concat()**
*Concat is used to combine ampscript and personalization strings into text strings.*

```
%%[VAR @block_a

IF ColumnA == "ValueA" OR ColumnA == "ValueB" THEN
  /* Panel 1 Message */
  SET @block_a = CONCAT("Some text goes here ", DCValue1, ", ", DCValue2, ", ", DCValue3, ", ", "rest of text")
 ELSE
  /* Panel 2 Message */
  SET @block_a = CONCAT("Some text goes here ", DCValue1, ", ", DCValue2, " or ", DCValue3, ". rest of text")

ENDIF

]%%
```

**BONUS ROUND: AttributeValue()**

I would use AttributeValue() AMPscript to grab your values instead of personalization strings to handle any null values.  It is definitely a life saver.

```
    %%[VAR @block_a

       SET @DCValue1 = AttributeValue('DCValue1')
       SET @DCValue2 = AttributeValue('DCValue2')
       SET @DCValue3 = AttributeValue('DCValue3')


IF ColumnA == "ValueA" OR ColumnA == "ValueB" THEN
      /* Panel 1 Message */
      SET @block_a = CONCAT("Some text goes here ", @DCValue1, ", ", @DCValue2, ", ", @DCValue3, ", ", "rest of text")
     ELSE
      /* Panel 2 Message */
      SET @block_a = CONCAT("Some text goes here ", @DCValue1, ", ", @DCValue2, " or ", @DCValue3, ". rest of text")
    ]%%
```

Comment: Great! Thanks so much. For the AttributeValue() solution, if there was a null value in the target DE, then this script would display a space, correct?

If I know the target DE does not have any null values then it seems Solution 1 would work best.

Comment: AttributeValue is always good practice - but yes, when displaying a personalization string, it will replace with nothing if the value is null or empty.